# Retrieve char defined in string

Tags: c++, string, function, char

I'm currently writing an assembler and VM program. My assembler reads in a .asm file and converts it to byte code that my VM then runs.

Currently I read in a line from my assembly file, break that line into it's components, and then determine what the line contains (is it a directive, or an instruction)

```
getline(assemblyFile, line);

istringstream iss(line);
vector<string> instruction{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),{}
};
```

This gives me a vector of strings that has been working well for me up to this point. If my directive is an int, I'm able to retrieve it simply by saying

```
mem[dataCounter] = stoi(instruction[VALUE]);
```

This was also working well when I was using ASCII values for my characters. However, I'm trying now to be able to provide either ASCII representation, or use a notation like

```
J       .BYT    'J'
```

Where the first J is a label, the .BYT tells me what data type it is, and my 'J' is the byte I'm wanting to store in my byte array. If I don't use quotes,

```
J       .BYT    J
```

the following works nicely

```
mem[dataCounter] = int(instruction[VALUE].c_str()[0]);
```

(gives me the decimal/byte value), where instruction is whole line, and VALUE is an index of 2. If I use the former, it of course returns the first quote. Not using quotes may be the solution in and of itself, however, I'm also having trouble reading in special characters, such as spaces, or newline characters. In the case of spaces, my directive looks like

```
SPACE   .BYT    ' '
```

which returns me a vector that has four elements, "SPACE", ".BYT", "'" and "'", and in the case of my newline which I've been attempting as

```
NEWLN   .BYT    \n
```

I have three elements with the last being "\n".

In none of these cases have I been able to find yet a way to retrieve the characters I am attempting to represent in my .asm file to their equivalent char/decimal value. I would like to continue to use string as it's been convenient and changing would require a fair bit of refactoring, but can be done to support the functionality.

What methods/functions are available that can help me retrieve these characters, in particular the special characters?

Comment: What does `instruction[VALUE]` contain? The whole string? I mean for this input `J       .BYT    'J'` for example.

Comment: instruction contains the whole line. VALUE is an index of 2, so instruction[VALUE] is a string containing the third element, 'J'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and treat special characters with caution.

For example, I would examine whether the token is a newline, and if it is explicitly state it.

For the `' '`, I would search for it in the string, and if found, remember its information (starting position for example in the string) and then erase it from the string. Afterwards, I would split into tokens.

Minimal Example for demonstrative purposes only:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  //std::string str ="SPACE   .BYT    \n";
  //std::string str = "J       .BYT    'J'";
  std::string str ="SPACE   .BYT    ' '";
  std::size_t start_position_to_erase = str.find("' '");
  if(start_position_to_erase != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Found: " << std::string(str, start_position_to_erase, start_position_to_erase+3) << std::endl;
    str.erase(start_position_to_erase, 3);
  }
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n", str.c_str());
  pch = strtok ((char*)str.c_str()," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    if(pch[0] == '\n')
        printf ("\\n");
    else
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Found: ' '
Splitting string "SPACE   .BYT    " into tokens:
SPACE
.BYT
```